# How to accept hash parameters in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Query:

I have a link like

```
<%= link_to "link_name", :controller => "some_controller", :action =>
"some_action", :id => "some_id", :first_param => {:second_param => "some
value"} %>
```

and in my routes.rb

```
map.connect '/some_name/:id' :controller => "some_controller", :action
=> "some_action"
```

Above code is giving me a URL like

```
http://localhost:3000/some_name/some_id
```

my requirement is to construct the URL as:

```
http://localhost:3000/some_name/some_id/value_inside_params[:first_param][:second_param]
```

Please help me out.

Thanks,

Saurabh

Answer (score 1):

You can use [route globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing):

```
map.connect '/some_name/:id/*other', :controller => 'some_controller',
            :action => 'some_action'
```

—this will make the additional parameters accessible within your action via `params[:other]`.

Comment: it is working for params[:other] but i want a url for params[:other][:first]